# SPSite Directory Selection (C#)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, spsite

I have a code that is running through all the Sites that we have created in SharePoint and finding the Sites that have documentation. When I create the SPSite object (?), I am defining a specific directory, but no matter what I seem to do, the script always runs through all the Sites in SharePoint, not just the sites in the specified directory.

Here's what the line of code looks like:
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://www.mysite.com/myprojects/ABC/"))

I'm trying to get the sites in the ../myprojects/ABC/ directory, but I am getting all the sites within mysite.com

Any ideas or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The more interesting part of the code would be the start of the iteration code.

Comment: What do you mean with "Sites that have documentation". What are you exactly looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The question is: what does your iteration code look like? If you do a site.OpenWeb(), then iterate recursively through the direct children using the SPWeb.Webs property, you should be fine.

Your behaviour sounds more like you are using site.AllWebs, which returns *all* sites (SPWeb) in the site collection.

Comment: To add to Paul-Jan's point;

new SPSite("http://www.mysite.com/myprojects/ABC/")

Creates a reference to the site collection that hosts that URL. If that's the root web in a site collection .OpenWeb().Webs will give you what you want.

If the site collection is actually http://www.mysite.com/ then you'll need to pull a reference to the SPWeb at /myprojects/ABC/ and then use .Webs

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462161.aspx